# Getting undefined when checking div values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done a similar case using textareas before that worked fined. However with divs im not getting the same results. When checking "previousVal" i get undefined, most likely because i'm not checking the value correctly.Because of this isChanged is always returning True even though no text change has been made anny of the divs. How do i extract the correct data to compare previousval with currentVal. The idea is simply to check weather anny textchanges has been made to the divs sence the page last loaded. If yes, then isChange should be true otherwise false.

HTML:

```
<h3>Handlartext1...</h3>
<div class="classA ClassB ClassC">Hello</div></textarea><br/><br />

<h3>Handlartext2...</h3>
<div class="classA ClassB ClassC">Bonjour</div></textarea><br/><br />

<h3>Handlartext3...</h3>
<div class="classA ClassB ClassC">Goddag</div></textarea><br/><br />

<input id="btnClick" type="button" value="Save and continue" />
```

Script:

```
  $('#btnClick').on("click", function () {
        if (CheckTextChange()) {
            alert('TRUE');
        } else {
            alert('FALSE');
        }
    })


    function CheckTextChange() {

        //Checks if values have changed in elements containing class="txt" 
        var isChanged = false;
        $('.ClassC').each(function () {
            var previousVal = $(this).get(0).defaultValue,
                currentVal = $(this).text();
            //alert( $(this).text()); //or $(this).text();

            if (currentVal != previousVal) {
                isChanged = true;
                alert(previousVal + ' changed into ' + currentVal);
            }
        });

        return isChanged;
    }
```

Comment: `</textarea>` ?? Why?

Comment: and i don't think divs have any default value???

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I believe you want a text box that, when submitted, shows whether there has been any change to the original.

This is the code i used to do this and a working JSFiddle below:

**HTML**

```
<h3>Handlartext1...</h3>
<div data-default="Hello" class="classA ClassB ClassC"><textarea>Hello</textarea><br/><br /></div>

<h3>Handlartext2...</h3>
<div data-default="Bonjour" class="classA ClassB ClassC"><textarea>Bonjour</textarea></div><br/><br />

<h3>Handlartext3...</h3>
<div data-default="Goddag" class="classA ClassB ClassC"><textarea>Goddag</textarea></div><br/><br />

<input id="btnClick" type="button" value="Save and continue" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#btnClick').on("click", function () {
        if (CheckTextChange()) {
            alert('TRUE');
        } else {
            alert('FALSE');
        }
    });


    function CheckTextChange() {

        //Checks if values have changed in elements containing class="txt" 
        var isChanged = false;
        $('.ClassC').each(function () {
            var previousVal = $(this).attr('data-default');
            console.log(previousVal);
            $textarea = $(this).find('textarea');
            var currentVal = $textarea.val();
            console.log(currentVal);

            if (currentVal != previousVal) {
                isChanged = true;
                alert(previousVal + ' changed into ' + currentVal);
            }
        });

        return isChanged;
    };
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjardine/qu83z76h/)

Answer (score -1):

You can mark the div with a dataset with default values and then you can compare it:

```
 <h3>Handlartext1...</h3>
 <div data-default-value="Hello" class="classA ClassB ClassC">Hello</div><br/><br />
```

I don't know why you need `</textarea>` so I removed it.

Then in Javascript:

```
 var previousVal = $(this).dataset().defaultValue;
 var currentVal = $(this).text();
```